# Product images not showing when turning flat category and products on

Tags: magento

I've built a module which fetches products fine from categories. products display good on frontend with nice looking images.

Now problem is if I turn flat categories and products on in system config.

Product is showing but the images are not displaying.

Is there any different way to fetch images for products in flat product?